# What does this mean about looting ? 略奪のかぎりをつくしてきた (MC is describing an enemy country/kingdom )

Tags: grammar, meaning, japanese-to-english

When reading, I met this expression which describes the looting of an enemy country, by the MC's kingdom/territory.
Many thanks to anyone who can explain the correct meaning to me.

> 略奪のかぎりをつくしてきた

My guess is "...they tried their best to loot/rob from other kingdoms/nations". But I'm not sure.

Full sentence:

> 戦闘国家アニマ……アルタニ領内への侵攻を繰り返し、**略奪のかぎりをつくしてきた**ライドネル王国の仇敵とも言える大陸の東にある国。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally Xの限りを尽くす means *to do X to the extreme/to the highest degree*. Practically, it is an expression to emphasize the degree of X.

略奪の限りを尽くす is almost a set phrase, it means *to rob/rip off (someone) mercilessly* or *to take whatever they want* in the particular context.

Similar usage:

- 暴虐の限りを尽くす to behave violently in the worst possible way.
- 飽食の限りを尽くす to eat every possible gorgeous food/to enjoy a variety of gourmet meals